# How to convert a Dataframe into a List of Lists (Scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So currently I have something that looks like this:

### Input:

### MemberID | CourseID

```
1                 3
1                 4
2                 3
2                 5
2                 6
```

Output:
List(List(3,4),List(3,5,6))

Comment: What have you tried? What problems did you have? Did you check out the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.package)? Why do you need this? Do you understand that the idea of **Spark** is to be a distributed framework whereas a `List[List[Any]]` is completely local and not so useful due the `Any`. Anyways: `df.collect.toList.map(_.toSeq.toList)`

Answer (score 0):

```
  val df = Seq((1,3),
    (1,4),
    (2,3),
    (2,5),
    (2,6)).toDF("MemberID", "CourseID")
  df.show(false)

  val resDF = df.groupBy("MemberID").agg(collect_list('CourseID).alias("CourseID"))
  val result = resDF.select(concat_ws(",", 'CourseID)).collect.toList.map(_.toSeq.toList)
//  +--------+--------+
//  |MemberID|CourseID|
//  +--------+--------+
//  |1       |3       |
//  |1       |4       |
//  |2       |3       |
//  |2       |5       |
//  |2       |6       |
//  +--------+--------+
//
//  df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [MemberID: int, CourseID: int]
//  resDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [MemberID: int, CourseID: array<int>]
//  result: List[List[Any]] = List(List(3,4), List(3,5,6))
```